# AJAX Page section reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload a page using AJAX every 10 seconds, so the page doesn't need to be refreshed and you can click a button to refresh the section.

The bit I want to reload is where all the threads of the forum are at this link:
http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=35

How would I fulfil this, meaning it refreshes just that page of the forum and adds any new threads?

Comment: Did you try something? AJAX calls or whatever ? Tell us what you have already tried so we can help you.

Comment: I don't really have anything sorry. The reason I asked is because I am not sure if or how you would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery load method. http://www.sitepoint.com/auto-refresh-div-content-jquery-ajax/

```
$(function(){        
            var $container = $("#content");
            $container.load("rss-feed-data.php");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
            {
                $container.load('rss-feed-data.php');
            }, 10000);
    });
```

Comment: But how would I tie that in with the link I just gave?

Comment: Ok. you mean, you need to load all threads from http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=35 page. and refresh it every 10 seconds

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. But prefereably just the first page.

Comment: Can you use an Iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

**METHOD 1**

Basically you will load the entire page each time, then find the element you want with Javascript and replace it with the one you just received. (in the snippet I'm assuming jQuery)

```
$(function() {
  //element to be replaced, according to your code
  var elementToBeReplacedId = "#ctl00_cphRoblox_ThreadView1_ctl00_ThreadList"

  //current url
  var refreshUrl = window.location.href;

  setInterval(function()  {
    $.ajax(refreshUrl)
     .done(function(data) {
       //data contains all the webpage. It is converted into a jqueryObject and then the thread container is searched
       var _$newElement = $(data).find(elementToBeReplacedId);

       if (_$newElement.length > 0 {
          //the old element is replaced with the new one
          $(elementToBeReplacedId).replaceWith(_$newElement);
       }
    })

  }, 10000);
}
```

**METHOD 2**

If you can split the forum webpage so that the threads block is indipendently reachable via a URL, you can edit the method I explained above and make it load just the threads frame. This method should guarantee better performance, since you won't have to load the entire page each time but only the necessary block.

Comment: How would I make it so the page didn't reload and only reloaded the thread bit? I know you said it but can you not show me the code?

Comment: Nvm, the first method works and doesnt refresh the page which is what I wanted. Thanks very much!